# Setting NODE_OPTIONS environment variable in Windows 10

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

I need to set NODE_OPTIONS variable for both --max-old-space-size and --max-semi-space size on windows 10.

I have tried setting the variable value to --max-old-space-size==8192&&--max-semi-space-size==128 but I got an error.

I then tried --max-old-space-size==8192;--max-semi-space-size==128 but I get an error too.

I am tried to set these values globally as environment variables.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Are you using command window or Powershell?

Comment: The error code reads Javascript heap out of memory. When I set --max-old-space-size to 8192; the error code reads Javascript heap out of memory. New semi space allocation failed.
When I set --max-semi-space-size to 128 the error reads Javascript heap out of memory. New old space allocation failed.
As such I want to try setting both old-space-size and semi-space-size.
I am using the command window